# open cv ip camera c++, connection refused

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, video-capture, ip-camera

I am trying to connect to my dlink ip camera using the following code:

```
//CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.2.74:554/0/1:1/main");
CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.2.74:554/ch1-s1");

if (camera == NULL) {

    printf("camera is null, aborting...");
    return;
}

printf("camera is not null\n");
fflush(stdout);
cvNamedWindow("img");

while (cvWaitKey(100) != 27) {

    IplImage *img = cvQueryFrame(camera);
    if (img == NULL) break;
    cvShowImage("img", img);
}

cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
```

and I am getting the following ERROR:

[tcp @ 0x103252d80] Connection to tcp://192.168.2.74:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.2.74/ch1-s1

camera is null, aborting...Program ended with exit code: 0

any ideas appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with the url.Try this:

```
"http://USER:PWD@IPADDRESS:8088/mjpeg.cgi?user=USERNAME&password=PWD&channel=0&.mjpg";
```

Comment: That fixed the connection refused issue, but getting WARNING: Couldn't read movie file http://admin:password123@192.168.2.74:554/mjpeg.cgi?user=admin&password=password123&channel=0&.mjpg
camera is null, aborting...Program ended with exit code: 0 

any way I can catch this error to get more info?

Comment: Try to check if opencv_ffmpegXXX.dll or opencv_ffmpegXXX_64.dll (if you are building 64bit executable) is in the same folder where your executable is. Replace XXX with the number of opencv version you use.

Comment: Will give this a try thanks. As a matter of interest, can this url (or format of the url) work on any IP camera provided the ip address and credentials are entered correctly?

Comment: To catch errors you should include exception.h and do a normal try and catch block.Ex: #include<exception.h>  try{ CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.2.74:554/ch1-s1");
}catch(const std::exception& ex)
{
   std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}

Comment: I have used that url in many IP cameras and it worked perfectly.My guess is it would change if not by models at least by brands.

Comment: tried copying both dll's opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll && opencv_ffmpeg_64 to the output directory, get this error now: [tcp @ 0x103252ea0] Connection to tcp://192.168.2.74:554 failed: Connection refused
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file http://admin:password123@192.168.2.74:554/mjpeg.cgi?user=admin&password=password123&channel=0&.mjpg
camera is null, aborting...Program ended with exit code: 0

will add exception handling to get more detail

Comment: not exception was thrown in the try catch, the cvCreateFileCapture simply returned null.

Comment: That means the connection was not established at all and no resource was returned.

Comment: Tried again with your suggested URL, don't know why but works now. Thanks